# iOS, tutorials for learning HTTPS:// communication with ATS

Tags: https, ios9

I am interested to learn how to use ATS in iOS apps to communicate with a server. Are there any good tutorials where I would be guided through the process of acquiring all the necessary stuff to use https, then actually implementing it in an iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

Here you find tutorial which explains ATS in detail. It also shows way to bypass ATS restrictions.

http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Comment: I definitely do NOT want to bypass it. That's not what I am looking for. Smth. like a tutorial that walks through the creation of a small app, illustrating all the intricacies of secure communication with ATS. I see a plenty of things like you posted here all around the internet, but do not see what I really need. That's why I asked. Maybe someone knows where to get it or could make it if there are none.